# Animate SVG path diagonal

Tags: css, animation, svg

I have a chart icon. X Y axis and an arrow pointing to top-right. I want this little arrow move out from top-right and come back from left-bottom. Smoth, cute little animation on hover. Sadly, moving the `left/right` properties doesn't work on paths, neither `margin` so I tried to use `translate`. So far, I got this. Can't figure out how to hide the arrow, when it moves to left-bottom :/ Any ideas? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xepdXO

```css
.chart {
  height: 66px;
  width: 88px;
  overflow: hidden;
 }

.arrow {
    animation: aaa 5s infinite;
}
  
@keyframes aaa {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0%);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate(800%, -500%);
  }
  75% {
    transform: translate(0%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(-800%, 500%);
  }
}
```

```html
  <svg class="chart" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1024 1024">
<path d="M992,832H64V160c0-17.7-14.3-32-32-32S0,142.3,0,160v704c0,17.7,14.3,32,32,32h960c17.7,0,32-14.3,32-32S1009.7,832,992,832
 z"/>
<path class="arrow" d="M992,192H736c-17.7,0-32,14.3-32,32s14.3,32,32,32h178.8L608.3,562.8L438,393.3c-12.5-12.5-32.7-12.4-45.2,0l-255.9,256
 c-12.5,12.5-12.5,32.8,0,45.2c6.3,6.3,14.5,9.4,22.7,9.4s16.4-3.1,22.7-9.3l233.3-233.4l170.3,169.5c12.4,12.4,32.8,12.4,45.2-0.1
 l329-329.3V480c0,17.7,14.3,32,32,32s32-14.3,32-32V224C1024,206.3,1009.7,192,992,192L992,192z"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: you only want it to show like going up ?? and not coming down??

Comment: from where exactly you want it to appear and disappear??

Comment: @JoykalInfotech I want the arrow go out on the top-right - hide - and come back from left-bottom. I have trouble with the hiding part :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can correct the animation like below:

```css
.chart {
  height: 66px;
  width: 88px;
  overflow: hidden;
 }

.arrow {
    animation: aaa 3s infinite linear;
}
  
@keyframes aaa {
  0%,100% {
    transform: translate(0%);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate(400%, -250%);
  }
  50.1% {
    transform: translate(-400%, 250%);
  }
}
```

```html
<svg class="chart" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1024 1024">
<path d="M992,832H64V160c0-17.7-14.3-32-32-32S0,142.3,0,160v704c0,17.7,14.3,32,32,32h960c17.7,0,32-14.3,32-32S1009.7,832,992,832
 z"/>
<path class="arrow" d="M992,192H736c-17.7,0-32,14.3-32,32s14.3,32,32,32h178.8L608.3,562.8L438,393.3c-12.5-12.5-32.7-12.4-45.2,0l-255.9,256
 c-12.5,12.5-12.5,32.8,0,45.2c6.3,6.3,14.5,9.4,22.7,9.4s16.4-3.1,22.7-9.3l233.3-233.4l170.3,169.5c12.4,12.4,32.8,12.4,45.2-0.1
 l329-329.3V480c0,17.7,14.3,32,32,32s32-14.3,32-32V224C1024,206.3,1009.7,192,992,192L992,192z"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: You are my hero, thank you! I see where did I meesed it up. I'm new to this animating thing.